# Install requests module show SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, installation, python-requests, python-3.5

[image]

Please view the image to help me find out what wrong with my code.

Comment: you have to run it in `cmd.exe`, not in Python Shell

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it in `cmd.exe`, not in Python Shell.

```
C:\> python -m pip install requests
```

or

```
C:\> pip install requests
```

Answer (score 1):

if its on windows

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to Python install directory
3. python -m pip install --upgrade pip
4. python -m pip install requests